# zf2 AbstractHttpControllerTestCase issue

Tags: zend-framework2

I came across an issue when using the `\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\Controller\AbstractHttpControllerTestCase` class to do controller tests. 
It seems that the third parameter on the `AbstractHttpControllerTestCase::dispatch()` method does not accept a multi-dimensional array.

E.g.

```
$this->dispatch('/controller/action', 'PUT', array('field1' => 'value1', 
                                                   'field2' => array(2,4)).
```

The method call above will throw an exception because the `$this->url()` method does not accept array values when using `'PUT'`. `'POST'` is OK though because it's not using `setContent()`.

I need to use array value because there are checkboxes in the form and I wanted to test the case when there are multiple values get submitted.

I wonder if anyone came across the same issue and managed to find a work around. I can override the `$this->url()` method but I am not quite sure whether it's something I am not doing correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I had to override the $this->url() method to handle array values.

This is what I had to change,

```
elseif ($method == HttpRequest::METHOD_PUT) {
        array_walk($params, function(&$item, $key)
                {
                    if (is_array($item)) {
                        $oldItem = $item;
                        $item = '';
                        foreach ($oldItem as $value) {
                            $item = ($item ? $item . "&" : $item);
                            $item .= $key . '[]=' . $value;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $item = $key . '=' . $item;
                    }
                }
        );
        $content = implode('&', $params);

        $request->setContent($content);
}
```